# Which one is correct? "due to (an|some|non-article) application error(s)

Tags: grammar, articles, zero-article

> (A) When a form submission fails due to an application error,
>
> (B) When a form submission fails due to some application errors,
>
> (C) When a form submission fails due to application errors,

Which one in the above is correct or more appropriate over the others?

Comment: More information is needed. How many application errors are needed to cause a submission failure? I suppose only one, but that is a technical question based on the code being run.

Comment: @user3169 oh i see! one app error can cause a submission  failure, so "an application error" should be the answer! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A looks the best.

*due to an application error*

We don't know how many errors occur in the future. Singular "an application error" is okay and natural. But if you and audience obviously know some errors are likely to occur, plural would be better.

"Form submission" looks uncountable to me. So leave "a" out.

When form submission fails due to an application error,...

Comment: thank you for your answer! does "an application error" imply both "only one error" and "one of the errors"?

Comment: Yes, they would mean either one, depending the user's case.